# Why doesn't objective-c allow pointers to a struct?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, struct

I was wondering why objective-c (ARC) does not allow me to use a  pointer to a struct (NSPoint, in this case)

My code works without one, I just want to question *why* it doesn't allow it as I have not found a reason on Google for it.

My current guess is because *structs cannot contain objects*, but I want to double check that; and want to know where the struct itself is saved. Thanks!

Comment: You can use pointers to structs. Could you provide some code?

Comment: `NSPoint point = NSMakePoint(1.23, 4.56); NSPoint * pointPointer = &point;` Works fine. What is it that you want to do with the pointer?

Comment: I mean, `NSPoint *point = NSMakePoint(1.5,1.6)` does not work, but `NSPoint point = NSMakePoint(1.5,1.6)` works because NSMakePoint returns a `NSPoint`, and not a `NSPoint *`, and I was wondering why this happens; and if this only applies to structs (I wouldn't do the same with a class)

Comment: Objective-C is perfectly happy using pointers to structs. The example you're giving (`NSPoint *point = NSMakePoint(1.5,1.6)` is invalid code; `NSMakePoint()` returns a structure, not a pointer to a structure, so you can't assign it to a pointer. If you want to create a function (or method, or block, or property, or ...) that returns a pointer to a struct (or union, or enum, or int, or float, or char, ...), Objective-C won't stop you.

Comment: Good to know; I haven't gotten my head around pointers yet fully. Why can't I have a non-pointer NSString?

Comment: Because interface types (which is what a NSString is) cannot be statically allocated.

Answer (score 3):

When migrating to ARC, the compiler no longer allowed this due to the complexity of how the struct containing object pointers would be initialized, copied, moved, or destroyed.

Apple called this out in the [Transitioning to ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) guides line the "ARC Enforces New Rules" section.

> - You cannot use object pointers in C structures.
>
>   - Rather than using a struct, you can create an Objective-C class to manage the data
>       instead.

However this is now allowed in LLVM as of [this commit](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/7275da0f2ee24336fe83cb7cfe2ba22f9cefc117).

To quote directly from the commit message:

> Declaring __strong pointer fields in structs was not allowed in
>   Objective-C ARC until now because that would make the struct
>   non-trivial to default-initialize, copy/move, and destroy, which is
>   not something C was designed to do. This patch lifts that restriction.
>
> Special functions for non-trivial C structs are synthesized that are
>   needed to default-initialize, copy/move, and destroy the structs and
>   manage the ownership of the objects the __strong pointer fields point
>   to. Non-trivial structs passed to functions are destructed in the
>   callee function.